# omnet++/veins : how to register interface entry for nic 80211p

Tags: omnet++, inet, veins

while trying to connect veins and inet, I've noticed my cars don't register 
the nic80211p interfaceEntry in the InterfaceTable. 
Indeed, the interfacetable contains only loopback l0 for every node.

In the omnet/inet manual it is written :

"Interfaces are registered dynamically in the initialization phase by modules that represent
network interface cards (NICs). The INET Framework makes use of the multi-stage initialization feature of OMNeT++, and interface registration takes place in the first stage (i.e.  stage
INITSTAGE_LINK_LAYER
)."

So if I understand the registration shoud be done in Nic80211p.ned and specifically in Mac1609_4::initialize()?

What do you think?

Thanks for any help.
Regards,

Comment: For the INET Framework that Veins 4.4 is compatible with, it is easiest to use the host auto configurator to register interfaces. This will make sure everything is set up as expected by the INET Framework. Other versions might behave totally different, but without knowing which versions you are using this is hard to guess.

Comment: Thank you Christoph. I'm using Inet 3.4.0 and veins4.4. I've added the registration interface in BaseMacLayer::registerInterface() in veins and now interfaces show ipv4 adresses.

Comment: But I'm facing another problem : Mac1609_4.ned rejects non WaveShortMessages. So Ipv4 messages are rejected...  "if ((thisMsg = dynamic_cast<WaveShortMessage*>(msg)) == NULL) {
  error("WaveMac only accepts WaveShortMessages");
 }"

Comment: This is a safety feature. The MAC layer was written for Wave Short Messages. Note that, if you use the INET Framework, you are most likely only interested in higher layer effects anyway, so it makes a lot of sense to use a MAC layer and a physical layer from the INET Framework instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked, the Veins repository on Github was amended to include a sample subproject (`veins_inet`) that runs an INET Framework (INET 3.4.0) simulation using Veins for nodes' mobility.

You can see the necessary code (and, after clicking on `Browse Files`, you can download a .zip archive of the complete project) on https://github.com/sommer/veins/commit/90d4586e